# How can I sequence redux actions after some async action completed in redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

#### Context

I have a lot of actions of the form: `LOAD_XYZ`,`LOAD_XYZ_FAIL`, `LOAD_XYZ_SUCCESS` for different page elements that need to be loaded.

I frequently wish to perform a redirect (`react-router`) after some item gets loaded, but since `redux-observable` does not return a promise I cannot perform the redirect in my component - but instead I have to do it using `redux` and `push('...')` from `react-router-redux`.

That unfortunately leads to a lot of duplication as I have `LOAD_XYZ` and `LOAD_XYZ_REDIRECT_TO` versions of the same action, plus two epics for each.

This is starting to feel wasteful and with too much redundancy

```
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`)
      .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    );

const fetchUserAndRedirectEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_AND_REDIRECT)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`)
      .concatMap(response => [fetchUserFulfilled(response), push(action.redirectTo)])
    );
```

---

#### Problem

Is there some sort of pattern/approach where I can sequence actions to be dispatched after some kind of async request has completed, to avoid redundancy and having to implement multiple versions of the same epic.

For example, I would like instead to have a separate `REDIRECT_TO` action that I can sequence after the item was loaded.

Something like these (imaginary) solutions:

```
dispatch(fetchUser(...)).then(redirectTo("..."))
dispatchSequence(fetchUser(...), redirectTo("..."))
```

I know `redux-thunk` can do this but then I miss out on all the rxjs operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably trenching into dangerous grounds but I did find a way to do this.

First we make a middleware which will add a completion observable as *metadata* to actions.

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export const AddListenerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const forkedAction = Object.assign({}, action, { meta: { listener: new Subject()}});
  next(forkedAction);
  return forkedAction.meta.listener.asObservable();
};
```

Since this is a `Subject` we can call `next` on it to emit some value. Creating a `notify` helper allows us to notify any subscribers of when the action has completed (plus pass down the data).

```
// notify doesn't consume but just emits on the completion observable
const notify = (action, fn) => source => 
  Observable.create(subscriber => 
    source.subscribe(emmission => {
      if (action.meta && action.meta.listener) {
        action.meta.listener.next(fn(emmission));
      }
      subscriber.next(emmission);
    })
  );

const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`)
      .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
      .pipe(notify(action, response => response.data))
    );
```

And now our dispatch returns an observable on which we can do standard rxjs operations. So this finally this becomes possible:

```
dispatch(fetchUser(...))
    .subscribe(({id}) => dispatch(redirectTo("/" + id)))
```

**Disclaimer: Use at your own risk!**